R - Plotly : How to reverse trace appearance and unify axes?
I have generated this 3D line plot. I'd like to code somethings:

I want the traces to be reversed by hour. For instance: The line at Hour 0 is towards the front and the line at hour 4 is at the back.
Additionally, I'd like the Intensity axis and hour axis to share a common 0

I have tried rotating the camera angle using this code;
scene = list(camera = list(eye = list(x = -1.25, y = 1.25, z = 1.25)))
However, it didn't reverse the order as I would like

Can you include some more code to make this reproducible?

I can't share the dataset I used to generate this plot, but I have it coded in Plotly like this:
fig <- plot_ly(DATA, x = ~RT, y = ~Intensity, z = ~Hour, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', color = ~Hour)

I found reversing the axis accomplishes what I want to for the ordering, use this fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(autorange = "reversed")))
I'm still figuring out how to unify the 0s on the axis
